# Displaying specific SQL Datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to display a start and end time for a SQL report. I always want to display the previous month period to look like:

> Start Time: Aug 1st 2014 00:00:00
>
> End Time: September 1st 2014 00:00:00

If the report was run in Oct it would give `Sept1-Oct1`. Not sure how to actually display that as a `Datetime` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `DATETIME` format, that would be

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AS StartTime,
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS EndTime
```

If you want to play around with character formats, you can do a bunch of things, like

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH,StartTime) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(StartTime) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' - ' + DATENAME(MONTH,EndTime) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(EndTime) AS VARCHAR(4)),
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,StartTime),3) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(StartTime) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' - ' + LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,EndTime),3) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(EndTime) AS VARCHAR(4))
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AS StartTime,
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS EndTime
  ) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if i misunderstood but is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,[date]) AS VARCHAR(12)) + '-' + CAST([date] AS VARCHAR(12)) FROM table
```

If you were to insert into your table a SMALLDATETIME such as

'2014-09-23 10:28:00'

then what would be produced is:

'Aug 23 2014 -Sep 23 2014 '

Comment: I would like it to say the 1st through the 1st (for the day) no matter what day the query is ran.

Comment: so in my example, what you want as output would be Aug 1 2014 - Sep 1 2014, correct?

Comment: Yes. and if I ran the query on 10/23 it would say Sept 1 - Oct 1 and so on. I should be able to run it on any day of the month and have it say the previous period.

Comment: @user3532047 take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b56b4/1  Its messy but that may be what your looking for

Comment: Isn't there a way to just make the entire thing a string except for the month? the '01' for the day will never change. Would just need dateadd(month,-1,getdate()) to show the previous month. Also would like to keep the year in there so it would know to put 2014 for jan 2015 query.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_SUB(Date,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS PastMonth`

would display one month prior to Date